# Getting access token in test environment in shopware account does not work, error 302

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

My app required an app server and api/search calls. It all works fine when the app is installed in our own shopware test shops.

But as the app is ready now I made an test environment in our shopware account. Installation including registration with our app server went fine. But all the api calls failed. The reason seems to be that I do not get an access token. The call for the access token gives me an 302 Found error.

But the code is ok as all works in our test shops, prod and dev.

So, what could be the problem in the sw account test environment?

Comment: What call do you make where you get the 302 status code? And what's the URL in the `Location` Header in the 302 response?

In theory you should get a access token during the registration process, and this access token can be used to access the API with the privileges requested by the App in the manifest file.

Comment: I make a POST call to api/oauth/token with grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                'client_id': ...id...,  'client_secret' => ...secret...,

Comment: I forgot the header location: http://....sw.testenvironment.de/shop/public.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! The shop url I got during registration was

"https://....sw.testenvironment.de/shop/public".

Api calls didn't work with this url.

But I changed it to

"https://....sw.testenvironment.de/shop/public/".

It worked.

The shopware test environment seems to have a problem with the /.
In our own shopware test shops it worked fine without the / at the end.